# Instagram get all the media via API -

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am using  https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API to integrate Instagram API for my application.

I have a requirement of getting all the media's for the 'self' user and display. I tried with min_id and max_id but it only show recent 20 media I also use max_timestamp and min_timestamp but nothing worked to me.

Is there something I missing or is there any work around to solve this issue.

Thanks
FJ

Comment: try using this one. It have a function to keep fetching new post until the last one. I'm not sure if it still working, my friend made this 
https://gist.github.com/shahril96/1e5b99080e1465c55d79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Live mode, with Sandbox mode you only get 20 posts, Test you app with Sandbox mode and request for live mode

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

First of all if your Instagram client is in Sandbox mode then you can't get more than 20 posts, more clearly last 20 posts. After client approve you can request more data using

```
MAX_ID  Return media earlier than this max_id.
MIN_ID  Return media later than this min_id.
COUNT   Count of media to return.
```

If client is in Sandbox mode then user should be also in Sandbox Users list. This list you can find when you click `manage` on your Instagram client.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Sandbox is the problem.

You can test your application by using a "real" token that you can get here :

[Pixel Union](http://instagram.pixelunion.net)